# How to test protected final method in Java using EasyMock?

Tags: java, testng, final, protected, easymock

I want to write test case for below **protected final method** in java using EasyMock. Is there any way to write test case of protected final method using EasyMock ?

I tried to write TC using Reflection approach,but it didn't work.

```
Class < ? extends Entity > type;
private Filter filter;
private Input input;
private transient Service access;
private transient ConfigDao confdao;

protected final Limitation getBaseLimitation() {
    Validate.notNull(type);
    GroupClass Group = new GroupClass(GroupTypeClass.SELECTOR);
    if (A.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
        filter = new Simple(A.ATTRIBUTE_ACTIVE, Operator.EQUALS, Boolean.TRUE); //A class has static final static String ATTRIBUTE_ACTIVE = "Active";
    }
    if (G.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
        filter = new Simple("position", Operator.EQUALS, Position.ACTIVE);
    }
    if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(confdao.getconfdao().getarea())) {
        if (U.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
            Validate.notNull(input, "switched on.");
            Object Inputobj = input.getInput();
            return access.getBaseLimitation(type, Inputobj, Group, filter);
        }
    }
    return access.getBaseLimitation(type, Group, filter);
}

public Simple(String path, Operator operator, Object value) {
    this(Path, operator, new Object[]{value});
}
```

**Any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: I personally would not recommend testing non-api (non-public) methods directly. Instead test the public methods that use this method. Protected methods are implementation details. It is possible to test non-public methods, but again I recommend against it.

Comment: We can write test case for protected methods using Reflection, but not sure about protected final methods.

Comment: If you know how to write a TC for a `protected` method just try how this works with `protected final` if you're not sure if it's possible. If you have any problems with that just come back and describe these problems.

Comment: I have tried the same approach for protected final, but it didn't work.

Comment: How didn't it work? Edit your question please.

Answer (score 1):

If you are mocking `getBaseLimitation()`, no, EasyMock can't help you because final methods can't be overridden. PowerMock could help you but I would personally just drop the `final`.

If you are testing it, you can from a class in the same package. But EasyMock is not needed to do so.

Then, `protected final` is not something useful. Why being protected if you don't want to be overloaded? You better be package scope or private.